# Calling a javascript variable inside a c# code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this `Javascript` function in my asp.net mvc4 with razor application

```
function openbox2(formtitle, fadin) {
         var self = $(this);
         var arr = self.data('arr');
         @{
         Session["element"] = @:arr;

                             }
         var box = document.getElementById('box');
         document.getElementById('shadowing').style.display = 'block';

         var btitle = document.getElementById('boxtitle');
         btitle.innerHTML = formtitle;

         if (fadin) {
             gradient("box", 0);
             fadein("box");
         }
         else {
             box.style.display = 'block';
         }
     }
```

**html part code**

```
<td> 
         <a href="#" onClick="openbox2('Validation de concept technique', 1)" data-arr="@fa.Id_element">Donner votre avis</a>. 
        </td>
```

My problem is that the instruction `Session["element"] = @:arr` didn't work even i replace it by `Session["element"] = "@:arr"`.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: is your js function on the cshtml file or in an external javascript file?

Comment: Going to need to do this with ajax or a socket.

Comment: Are you trying to set a session variable via JavaScript? that simply won't work

Comment: the js function is in the same cshtml file

Comment: @p.s.w.g - You can do it, just not directly like that.

Comment: @p.s.w.g i need to store the value of the variable not necessarily in  session variable

Comment: @TravisJ How can i do that?

Comment: @Lamloumi - Setting up a controller which accepts the same structure and then posting the variable there with ajax will allow you to store something in Session which came from client side. However, this seems like an XY problem. What is the goal of storing this information in the Session or in your application's scope?

Comment: @TravisJ by clicking into the link , a lightbox appears which contains the row ,identified by `@fa.Id_element` value, informations.When i submit the lightbox form i 'd like to get the `@fa.Id_element` of the row to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just can't.

you **can** set values in javascript coming from your server side, but you can't do it the other way.

what you can do, is to send an ajax request on page load with this array, so it will be saved in the `Session` variable on server side.

something like:

```
$(function(){
    $.post('/saveArray', {items:arr});
});
```

hope that helps.