# Post a new variable in the same view by Ajax && Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i'd to use the `.post` ajax's function to post a variable in my view. i had this problem and i posted it here : [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547546/calling-a-javascript-variable-inside-a-c-sharp-code), so i'm now trying to solve it by the use of `Ajax`

**View : index.cshtml**

```
<td> 
         <a href="#" onClick="openbox2('Validation de concept technique', 1)" data-arr="@fa.Id_element">Donner votre avis</a>. 
        </td>
```

and

```
<form method="Post" action="/User/Validate_Expert_Decision" target="_parent">
   <span>
        <b style="color:red" >
        Votre justification * 
        <b />

          <br />
          <br />
      <textarea rows="10" cols="75" name="justification"></textarea>
    </span>
      <input type="hidden" name="element" value="@Request.Params["element"]" />

    <p> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Annuler" onClick="closebox()">
    </p>
</form>
```

**the javascript function**

```
 function openbox2(formtitle, fadin) {
         var self = $(this);
         var arr = self.data('arr');
         $.post("/index.cshtml", { element: arr });

         var box = document.getElementById('box');
         document.getElementById('shadowing').style.display = 'block';

         var btitle = document.getElementById('boxtitle');
         btitle.innerHTML = formtitle;

         if (fadin) {
             gradient("box", 0);
             fadein("box");
         }
         else {
             box.style.display = 'block';
         }
     }
```

**controller : Validate_Expert_Decision**

```
 public ActionResult Validate_Expert_Decision() 
 {
     string id_element = Request.Params["element"];
     return RedirectToAction("Display_Task_List", new { id_project = id_project});
 }
```

the problem is that i always get an empty value of `id_element` in `string id_element = Request.Params["element"];`.

What are the reasons of this error? How can i fix it?

Comment: why aren't you using @Html.Form instead of writing your own form element?

Comment: what can `@Html.Form` change in this case??

Comment: @Liam if i understood you , you don't have a solution . thanks for your intervention

Comment: My eyes are hurting from reading the code from this question :). So many errors. I hope this is a personal project or your learning, if not... Please see some tutorials and best practices and review your code before it goes to production.

Comment: @hjgraca can you explain please ? what errors you speak about?

Comment: @Lamloumi, never use inline javascript onClick="closebox()". Never access Request or Response Objects in Mvc, hard coding a url "action="/User/Validate_Expert_Decision", use BeginForm instead. What is this $.post("/index.cshtml", { element: arr });? Mvc does not have a url that points to index.cshtml... You use Jquery $(this) and other times you dont document.getElementById. Its a mess basicly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to post an ajax request you must use urls in this pattern:

```
/Area/Controller/Action
```

in your ajax request you specify your view name, but url for ajax request must be:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("ActionName, ControllerName, new { Area = "AreaName" }")", { element: arr });
```

and if you don't have area, just remove last argumant.

Instead of `Request.Params["element"]` you can easily get your variables by argumant in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Validate_Expert_Decision(string element)
```

** If you want to learn ASP.Net MVC i suggest you to read this book:
[Pro ASP.Net MVC 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361)

This is one of best books that i have read until now